# image overlay on site but keeping content clickable

Tags: html, css, png

The designer of a site I am working on requires that some subtle designs be scattered around *on top of the content* of the site. These designs are all in a PNG which is mostly transparent. The only way I can figure out to get this to work is to put a div over the entire site, and make its background that image. This looks correct, but renders the site unusable, since nothing behind the overlay can be clicked (even though it can be seen). If I change the z-index of the overlay so that things can be clicked, then the overlay ends up behind other elements, which is not allowed.

[Here's a JS fiddle demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/ncf8nex5/)—basically:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="some picture"/>
        <p>Here's some shiny happy content.
            <a href="#alink">Click me!</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

.wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: [the mostly transparent image with side designs];
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

That link will then be unclickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the overlay.

Comment: This is a horrible solution because of the lack of browser support http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: While it's not supported universally, I only see IE being an issue there...so I would not call it a horrible solution. It's not a silver bullet though.

Comment: Another solution that allows you to keep the overlay and not use pointer-events, is make the <p> also absolutely positioned relative to the wrap, and then position that so that it has a higher z-index than the overlay.

Comment: @Alex I didn't mean to use such a strong word but the principle still applies. If it were an intranet site where you have control over your users' browsers that'll make sense but for an internet site is really a bad solution considering that there's A LOT of users running IE 8,9,10 and I mean a lot

Comment: @Alex for example look at some browser market share stats here http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php... you can blindly assume that even IE7 with a 2% share could represent millions of users

Comment: @Leo I suppose I should've mentioned that browser support isn't the best. Assuming this is a design embellishment and not a necessity, I would use Modernizr to detect pointer-event support and hide the overlay for older IE.

Comment: Yes, I acknowledged it's not a silver bullet. I understand browser market share. I offered an alternative solution above as well if the OP wants to support IE, or they can do what Brandon suggests to support the IE crowd through Modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

Why should the overlay be a `background-image`?
Just make it an `img`. You can't click on what you can't see anyway.

edit: cut up the overlay into pieces to minimize the transparent areas, and add the `img` elements to the normal HTML flow.

Comment: +1 this makes a lot of sense from the usability and practical point of view

Answer (score 0):

Clone whatever you have under the image (do not copy IDs, of course), place above the image and make it transparent too.

```
.content-above {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 10;
}
```

opacity should be done cross-browser way. Look at example below

http://jsfiddle.net/ncf8nex5/1/

Text will not be selectable, of course, but links will work.

ps: And I'm not mentioning image maps ))