# How can I exclude an element class from being a target in jquery .click() event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched around the net for an answer to this, but no cigar, so here is my issue.

I have two HTML divs; both contained in a wrapper div, but one has z-index:101 in it's CSS, along with width and height 100%. This, naturally, places it "over" (z-index wise) the other div, .object, when a jquery click event is fired. This causes this overlay div to be the click's e.target, but I need to have the .object class be the target. Thus, it is possible (and if so, how) to exclude an HTML element from a jquery click event?

For reference, the jquery click event code I'm using:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
            if(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains("object")) {
                globalSelected.classList.remove('selected') ;
                globalSelected=e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
                globalSelected.classList.add('selected') ;
            } else {
                globalSelected.classList.remove('selected') ;
                globalSelected=null;
            }
});
```

Comment: You could use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: Using `.not()` wouldn't work. The overlay still captures the click event, you just aren't doing anything with it. Here's a demo to illustrate: http://codepen.io/btpoe/pen/ljKkA

Comment: I actually found the solution to my own question mere minutes after posting the question, despite having googled for hours beforehand. I merely needed to add pointer-events:none; to the CSS of the overlay. And like Brandon said, .not doesn't work.

Comment: That's awesome. Could you post it as an answer?!?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.object').trigger('click');
});
```

Without more context, I'm not sure if this will cause any undesirable side-effects.

Comment: I actually found the solution to my own question mere minutes after posting the question, despite having googled for hours beforehand. I merely needed to add pointer-events:none; to the CSS of the overlay. Anyways, the below is why your solution would not work, unfortunately.

    `<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div class="object"></div>
    </div>`

Comment: That is certainly a valid option if you don't need support for IE10 or older. I actually suggested that solution to someone else and was told it was a horrible solution, which is why I shied away from suggesting it again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26007816/4067275

Comment: My solution would work for you, you would just need to change `id="overlay"` to `class="overlay"`. Speaking of which, unless you are positive that will be the only overlay on the entire page (and any other page that element might show up on), you're probably going to want to either make it a class or consider renaming it.

Comment: Considering I am writing the HTML of the page myself, I am absolutely positive it is the only overlay on the page. It's for a JS web game, so yeah. Also, I am using a ton of JS stuff which IE can't use, so I can't support IE in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution to my own question mere minutes after posting the question, despite having googled for hours beforehand. I merely needed to add pointer-events:none; to the CSS of the overlay.